# ADO.NET Data Service API Versioning

Tags: versioning, wcf-data-services

We created an ADO.NET Services on top of our EDMX file as the main entry point for our central application. In the near future a lot of distinct applications will show up and consume our REST Service.

So far, so good but there is one thing I'm missing. I don't want to update all my consumers each time a new version of the ADO.NET Data Services is published. How can I achieve such a legacy compliance?

Thank you,
Stéphane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data services client and server do not do version negotation at connection time - they do it for every request. Each request or respond includes a version header that indicates what version of client or server is required to service that request. This means that a downlevel client can communicate with an up-level server so long as the server can respond to those requests without doing anything that requires it to up the version number of the response. Features that require the service to use higher version responses are all off by default.

What this means is that as new version of Data Services are published, the client and server will continue to be able to communicate with each other regardless of which version is installed on the client so long as new features have not been enabled on the server that require a higher version client to respond.

Comment: nice explanation. Links to the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473427(v=vs.103).aspx